# Ruby 'if' condition in rjs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rjs

I want to insert a user in the userlist only if the user object (@row) is not nil. How do I do the insert conditionally in an rjs template?

> page.insert_html :bottom, :userlist,
>   render(:partial => "user", :locals =>
>   { :user => @row, :myid => @row.id })

thanks much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
page.insert_html :bottom, :userlist, render(:partial => "user", :locals =>  { :user => @row, :myid => @row.id }) unless @row.blank?
```

Answer (score 3):

exactly how you would do it in regular ruby

```
if @row
  page.insert_html(:bottom, :userlist, render(:partial => "user", :locals =>  { :user => @row, :myid => @row.id }))
end
```

or if you want it on one line

```
page.insert_html(:bottom, :userlist, render(:partial => "user", :locals =>  { :user => @row, :myid => @row.id })) if @row
```

Comment: A lot of people don't realize that .rjs files are actually Ruby.